# Was the factional civil war that broke out in Angola after its independence in 1975 based on tribal rivalry?

Tags: cold-war, africa, ethnicity, civil-war, angola

Was the factional civil war that broke out in Angola after its independence from Portugal in 1975 primarily based on tribal rivalries.        (with an ideological cover)?

Answer (score 5):

Broadly, yes.

- The MPLA's main support was among the [Ambundu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambundu) people.
- UNITA's main support came from the [Ovimbundu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ovimbundu) tribe of central
  Angola.
- The FNLA's main support came from the [Bakongo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kongo_people) people in the North.

But it quickly became a proxy conflict within the wider Cold War though.

See also:

- [What became of the plan to partition Angola?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/11228/24858)
- [What was Yugoslavia doing in the Angolan Civil War?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/38508/24858)